# Email opt-out is not reflecting in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

we are using salesforce marketing cloud V5 connector to connect between salesforce and marketing cloud

when we check email opt-out in contact, it is not reflecting in all subscribers in marketing cloud

is this issue with V5 connector or any other thing we are missing here

Comment: We are dealing with a similar case. This was already helpful, but I was wondering if there is a way to automate this?

Comment: Hello @JulieM if you click on the "Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe" it should update in the marketing cloud. But if you are looking other way then you need to write custom Code(ampscript) to update back in salesforce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the configuration of the Marketing Cloud Connector, there are instructions to [customize the Contacts Objects page layout.](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/configure_the_crm/update_page_layouts/) 
 Specifically, you need to add the ContactActions Visualforce page to the page layout.

The page includes three links, 'Send Marketing Cloud Email', 'View Marketing Cloud Analytics', & 'Marketing Cloud Unsubscriber'.  When you click the 'Markting Cloud Unsubscribe' link, the Email Opt-Out field in Salesforce and the Subscriber Status in Marketing Cloud are kept in-sync.

Comment: Hello @David Devoy , I added three custom links in the contact page layout and tested by clicking 'Marketing Cloud Unsubscriber'. Still it is not synced with marketing cloud

Comment: I'll have to test this out.  I know this is how it used to work. But, the Connector has gone through many enhancements since then (2015).

Comment: Does a subscriber record in Marketing Cloud with the subscriberkey equal to the contact_id?

Comment: Hello @David we tested with integrated user and its working fine now.  Thank you very much for helping me out

Comment: Right that make sense.  The visualForce page would probably fail to execute if the Salesforce users was not integrated with Marketing Cloud.